# Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars Scikit Learn

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the SGCD model of Scikit Learn but I have an error. I think it's a problem with the shape of my arrays but I don't understand how to solve it.

I did resize my images so that they were all the same shape.

[Here is my X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWYUY.png)

[Here is my y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tz1i.png)

```
import cv2

def pixel_grayscale(file):
  file = file.split()
  if len(file) == 2 :
    image = imread("chi/"+file[0], as_gray=True)
  else :
    image = imread("muf/"+file[0], as_gray=True)
  image = cv2.resize(image,(128,128), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
  return np.reshape(image,(128*128))

extract["pixel_grayscale"] = extract.apply(lambda row:
  pixel_grayscale(row.file) if row.category == 0 else pixel_grayscale(row.file+" chi"), axis=1)

features = ["pixel_grayscale"]

X = extract[features]

y = extract["category"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

sgdc = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=0.01)

sgdc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

This is the error :

```
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, average=False, class_weight=None,
          early_stopping=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True,
          l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='optimal', loss='hinge',
          max_iter=1000, n_iter_no_change=5, n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
          power_t=0.5, random_state=None, shuffle=True, tol=0.01,
          validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-250-8d4e62f2d3f6> in <module>()
      4 print(sgdc)
      5 
----> 6 sgdc.fit(X_train, y_train)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and what shapes they have.

Comment: The skipped frames may help narrow this down, but apparently it's having problems making a numeric dtype array from either `X_train` or `y_train`.  Most likely because it is a list or object dtype array with a mix of element sizes.

Answer (score 0):

From the image, it looks like you have an array embedded for every value in 'pixel_grayscale' . This can't be used for fitting a model.

So assuming the length of each array is the same, you can expand the columns into a dataframe with the correct number of columns. For example, this looks like your data frame:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'pixel_grayscale':[np.random.uniform(0,1,5) for i in range(20)]})
y = pd.Series(np.random.binomial(1,0.5,20))

X.head(5)

                                     pixel_grayscale
0  [0.6434161648260968, 0.017854434974394873, 0.4...
1  [0.26917214129827793, 0.09492344774577577, 0.3...
2  [0.22517655723236796, 0.8571416063239798, 0.50...
3  [0.5969653146755568, 0.060240887971164, 0.3594...
4  [0.25819470145953516, 0.9541893368409663, 0.98...
```

If I run your code I get the same error:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

sgdc = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=0.01)
sgdc.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Check that every entry has same length, you should get only 1 value:

```
X['pixel_grayscale'].apply(len).value_counts()

5    20
```

Now we expand the entries into columns and this works:

```
X_expanded = pd.DataFrame(X['pixel_grayscale'].tolist())
sgdc = SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=0.01)
sgdc.fit(X_expanded, y)
```

Comment: It works!
If I want to add a feature, for example extract["pixel_color"] to this new dataframe that is the same shape, how can I do that?

Comment: `X_expanded = extract["pixel_color"] `, assuming your `extract["pixel_color"]` is not an embedded list